# Relative imports in MS VS Community 2017

Tags: python, python-import

I have a solution in MS VS Community 2117 and within this solution there are two projects. This looks like

```
solution-
        |
        |-project A-
        |          |
        |          |-A.py
        |-project B-
                   |
                   |-B.py
```

And I'm going to import a class (let's it is also named A) from A.py to B.py. However when inside B.py I try to write

```
from .A import A
```

`.A` is not visible.

Can I use relative imports to set a relation between modules of two projects or am I doing something wrong?

I am using CPython 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports can be used in packages. To make a package you need to add an empty file called `__init__.py` in each directory that you would like to make a package. Then you import including the directory which imports it as a package:

for example:

```
main.py

solution/
|
|- __init__.py
|
|-- project_a/
|          |
|          |- __init__.py
|          |- a.py
| 
|-- project_b/
           |
           |- __init__.py
           |- b.py
```

a.py:

```
print "Hello A"
```

to import ../project_a/a.py into b.py:

```
from solution.project_a import a

print "Hello B"
```

from main.py you would import the b as a package:

```
from solution.project_b import b

print "Hello Main"
```

Now when you execute main.py:

```
Hello A
Hello B
Hello Main
```

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken but I read that CPython 3.6 made this trick redundant.